# iterators for vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I read another post that answered a question regarding iterators for vectors of pointers. I tried to use the same concept in my code but I receive some compilation errors. The code sample I was basing my code on is:

```
vector<c*> cvect;
cvect.push_back(new sc);
vector<c*>::iterator citer;
for(citer=cvect.begin(); citer != cvect.end(); citer++) {
    (*citer)->func();
}
```

I want to use a similar concept to create a deep copy constructor for a class that has two data members that are vectors of pointers to objects. My code is similar to this:

```
class MyContainer {
    vector<MyStuff*> vecOne;
    vector<MyStuff*> vecTwo;

 public:
    MyContainer(const MyContainer& other);
};

MyContainer::MyContainer(const MyContainer& other) {
    // copy vector one
    vector<MyStuff*>::iterator vec1_itr;
    for (vec1_itr = other.vecOne.begin(); vec1_itr != other.vecOne.end(); vec1_itr++) {
        vecOne.push_back(new MyStuff(vec1_itr));
    }

    // copy vector two
    vector<MyStuff*>::iterator vec2_itr;
    for (vec2_itr = other.vecTwo.begin(); vec2_itr != other.vecTwo.end(); vec2_itr++) {
        vecTwo.push_back(new MyStuff(vec2_itr));
    }
}
```

I get some compilation errors like:

> /path/MyContainer.cpp:38: error: no match for '`operator=`' in '`vec1_Itr = other->MyContainer::vecOne. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = MyStuff*, _Alloc = std::allocator<MyStuff*>]()`'
>
> candidates are: `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyStuff*, std::vector<MyStuff, std::allocator<MyStuff> > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyStuff*, std::vector<MyStuff, std::allocator<MyStuff> > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyStuff*, std::vector<MyStuff, std::allocator<MyStuff> > >&)`

I also get an error for `operator!=`... And another set of the same errors for the other vector.

Comment: How you have declare `vecOne` and `vecTwo` in `class MyContainer`?

Comment: On side note, try to use `MyStuff` copy constructor instead of passing an iterator to it. You can call it as, `...(new MyStuff(**vec1_itr)`. This will be simpler

Comment: Beware if the vector can contain pointers to objects of types derived from `c`, which is legal, as you would be *slicing* them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the iterators. Try this instead:

```
vecOne.push_back(new MyStuff( **vec1_itr ));
```

#### Edit 0:

Yes, should be double dereference (fixed above). And it should be the `const_terator` instead since you are dealing with `const` containing object:

```
vector<MyStuff*>::const_iterator vec1_itr;
```

Comment: The error is telling him he's violating the `const`. It has nothing to do with the constructor of his class.

Comment: to invoke MyStuff copy constructor, it should be called as: `MyStuff(**vec1_itr)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @wilhelmtell, @Nikolai, and @iammilind.
Changing to the `const_iterator` and properly dereferencing the iterator in my `.push_back(new MyStuff(**vecX_itr));` solved my problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing these double dereferences of my `const_iterator` even though they appear to function correctly. The 1st vector of ptrs to `MyStuff` objects is a master list. In the 2nd vector of ptrs to `MyStuff` objects, the ptrs all point to a subset of `MyStuff` objects pointed to by the 1st vector. I am concerned that I have unrelated vectors where the 2nd vector is pointing to elements that are independent of the 1st vector. The `other` object's vector elements are read from a file. Should the copy constructor just read the file? `other` holds a reference to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

Either don't take the parameter as `const` or declare `vec1_itr` as a `const_iterator`. The issue here is that `vecOne.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` because the container is `const`. If you want to change the container you'll have to remove the `const` qualifier.

On a side note, if holding a container of pointers means you need to manage the pointers in the container and you have two such containers then you should move the container into a class of its own. Try to avoid managing more than one resource in a class.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your second comment. I have two classes that I am working with. Objects instantiated from the first class hold several pieces of data. Objects of the second class hold a few simple pieces of data plus two vectors of pointers to objects of the first class. I am doing this to minimize any need to copy objects derived from the first class. The 1st vector is like a master list and the 2nd vector is a subset of the master list. Does that make sense? And thanks for your comments on the `const_iterator`. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: Perfect. The `const_Iterator` solved two errors and as stated above the adjusting the `.push_back` code to `vecOne.push_back(new MyStuff(**vec1_itr));` solved the other errors.

Answer (score 3):

**!! MEMORY LEAK ALERT !!**

Your code, as is, is leaky.

Any exception thrown from within the copy constructor (`std::bad_alloc` ?) will cause a memory leak because the memory passed into the `vector` will never be cleaned-up (the destructor won't be called since the object was never constructed in the first place).

You could, of course, add the required `try/catch`, though I warn you that the code will soon get clunky (you need several).

This is a direct result of violating rule **1** of resources management:

> An object should manage **at most one** resource, in which case it should not be doing anything else.

This means that if your object is a *business* object (with application logic inside) then it should not deal with resource management directly, but instead use already existing managers.

In your case, you have two solutions:

1. *Recommended*: since you do not use polymorphism here, don't use pointers. `std::vector<MyStuff>` is perfectly fine
2. If you need polymorphism, but didn't included it in this toy example, then use `boost::ptr_vector<MyStuff>`

*Bonus Point:* the two of them define sensible copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors, so that you won't have to rewrite them yourself.

**EDIT:**

As noted by @David, if you need polymorphism, you cannot use copy construction, and thus need:

- a `clone` method, or equivalent
- pointers and dynamic memory allocation

`boost::ptr_vector` provide all you need for this (with automatic use of the `clone` method when copying).

Comment: +1, and for the asker's sake: do *note* that if you need polymorphism the other solutions won't make it work, copy construction will *slice* the contained objects.

Comment: I appreciate all these additional comments. In my case this project is really an exercise in basic memory allocation/management, use of vectors and some file I/O mixed in. For my purposes it is safe to assume that the constructor will never fail. I understand that this would not be acceptable in professional code.